# Generating random bytes doesn't work on hosting domain

Tags: php, hosting

I've a problem with code to generate random bytes for an automatic username field. It's successful when I tried it on my localhost:

[image: Success]

But when I tried it on by hosting domain, it was unsuccesful:

[image: Unsuccessful]

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="input" class="form-control" readonly="" value="<?php $bytes=random_bytes(5); echo bin2hex($bytes);?>" required="required">
    </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with this? Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: [random_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) is php7 only. Maybe your hoster has old php version?

Comment: Is there alternative ways?

Comment: Yes. It's 5. Would u suggest me an alternative way?

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the version. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(5)`, works in PHP 5.3+

http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="input" class="form-control" readonly="" value="<?php $bytes=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(5); echo bin2hex($bytes);?>" required="required">
    </div>
</div>
```